# Javascript - Clearing the interval and setinterval scope

Tags: javascript, ajax, scope, setinterval, clearinterval

I have some AJAX that shows a progress bar using `setInterval()` to get the scripts current progress. My problem is that I cannot seem to kill it when progress has reached 100%. I am not sure if this has something to with scope, but my handler is global, so I can't figure out why it's not working. Here's what I have:

```
function showLog(){
    document.getElementById('log').style.display = "block";
    clearInterval(inth);
    return false;
}

function startAjax(){
    var inth = setInterval(function(){
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ xmlhttpp=new XMLHttpRequest();}else{ xmlhttpp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }
        xmlhttpp.onreadystatechange=function(){
            if(xmlhttpp.readyState==4 && xmlhttpp.status==200){
                document.getElementById("sbar").innerHTML=xmlhttpp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttpp.open("POST","scrape.php",true);
        xmlhttpp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var sitelist = document.getElementById('website').value;
        var par = "website="+sitelist;
        xmlhttpp.send(par);
    }, 5000);
    return false;
}
```

Why is clearInterval not working? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where's the code that decides when it's reached 100%?

Comment: @Jack It's printed in `scrape.php` once progress has reached 100%. Originally I tried a `if(xmlhttpp.responseText == "100%")` type of thing but that didn't work out so well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a scope issue, declare the `var inth` outside the function as a global variable. and use `inth = setInterval(...)` in the `startAjax` function.

As you said in your question, your handler is global. But the variable itself is not, so it can't be accessed outside the scope of the function.